# NoReverseMatch at / Reverse for 'delete_order' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['delete_order/(?P<pk>[^/]+)/$']

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

I am using `<str:pk>` to delete a specific data in table. But this is not working. I followed a tutorial with no avail, here is what I get:

> NoReverseMatch at /
>
> Reverse for 'delete_order' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['delete_order/(?P[^/]+)/$']

views.py

```
def deleteOrder(request, pk):
    order = anime.objects.get(id=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        order.delete()
        return redirect('/')

    context={'list':order}
    return render(request, 'main/delete.html',context)
```

table.html

```
    <td><a href="" class="btn btn-success">Update</a></td>
    <td><a href="{% url 'delete_order' order.id %}" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
{% endfor %}
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.homepage,name ="homepage"),
    path('anime/',views.addAnime,name="anime"),
    path('delete_order/<str:pk>/', views.deleteOrder, name="delete_order"),
]
```

I can't seem to find anything wrong with my code.

Comment: Please add `for` opening code from your template and the view code which is rendering `table.html`, not `delete.html`.

Comment: obviously - from the error message - `order.id` doesn't resolve to a valid value in your template (so what the `url` tag sees is an empty string).  Now why it's the case, no one can tell from what you posted, so please provide a proper [mcve].

Comment: you're passing `list` to your template, not `order`. So in your template you need to use `list.id`. Or rename your context variable to `order`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your table.html does not know the value of `order.id`. I would expect the view which is rendering table.html passes `order` to the template via a context parameter. I think this is what Ivan Starostin is suggesting as well. So in this view you would want to have something like

```
context = {
        'order': order,
    }
return render(request, 'table.html', context))
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial03/#a-shortcut-render for more information.

Comment: you're not passing it via the `request`, you're just adding `order` to the context in which template is rendered.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I edited it, thanks